# Azure diagnostics cleanup

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics

How can tables created by Azure diagnostics (WAD*) be periodically cleanup? So far i've found only some powershell cmdlets. May be there is a better way?

Comment: What would qualify as a better way? There are third-party tools like [Azure Diagnostics Manager](http://www.cerebrata.com/products/azure-diagnostics-manager/introduction) that are able to prune diagnostics data (e.g. by date) but I am not sure about any periodic cleanup.

Comment: Thanks for the useful link. Please, post it as answer. Ideally, i'd prefer not to use 3rd party tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're some 3rd party tools which implement this functionality. One such tool is [Cerebrata Azure Management Cmdlets](http://www.cerebrata.com/products/azure-management-cmdlets/features) using which you can automate diagnostics cleanup by creating some PowerShell script and scheduling them.

Since the diagnostics data is stored in Windows Azure Storage, you can write some code as well to clean up old data. When cleaning, please remember **`NOT to query on Timestamp`**. [Instead use PartitionKey as it denotes a date/time value in Ticks](http://gauravmantri.com/2012/02/17/effective-way-of-fetching-diagnostics-data-from-windows-azure-diagnostics-table-hint-use-partitionkey/).

Answer (score 0):

[Windows Azure Scheduler](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/scheduler/) is in preview version now.
One of the [usages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn479785.aspx):

> Daily maintenance: Web applications have needs such as daily pruning of logs, performing backups, and other maintenance tasks.

So, let's wait until release version.